# How to call "requestContext.update()" several times with Primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In a bean, I'd like to:

```
//modify some component dynamically.  
RequestContext#update(component);  
Thread.sleep(1000);  
//modify some component dynamically.   
RequestContext#update(component);
```

But it seems that the update happens just once, when the method returns.

How could I achieve this effect? (multiple updates from a bean).

Comment: tell us more about your requisite, updating the same component twice in a single request makes no sense.

Comment: You can call the `update` method with a collection of components id.

Comment: Ok sorry. My app receives new values pushed from somewhere else. In my bean, I have a loop checking for the arrival of a new value.  When one arrives, the value in a component is changed, and requestContext.update is called for this component (this would mimick a push). But no update happens, only one when the loop is exited and the method in the bean returns.